# Datatable doesn´t work correctly with serverSide: true

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables

I'm making a web application where I have a datatable that is filled with data from a database. I do this through Ajax. My code is:

```js
$('#promotionTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
       "url": "{{url('api/promotion/index')}}"
    },
    "columns":[
       {sWidth : "50%", data:'name', name: 'promotions.name'},
       {sWidth : "50%", data:'price', name: 'promotions.price'},
    ],
});
```

However, the datatable does not work well.

For example, it does not filter the search and many pages appear to me when I have a single data (Image).

[image]

Comment: Please show the response from your script `api/promotion/index`.

Comment: I add a comment with this

Comment: You need to show the actual response as displayed in the broswer developer tools 'Network' console.  I'm guessing that you're not returning the parameters that datatables is expecting. Have a look at the Returned data section [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)